# What's the difference between root-relative and protocol-relative url paths?

Tags: url, path, protocols

In practice, I've seen that a root-relative URL like /some-resource will automatically resolve to the same same protocol and domain as its parent page. That said, Googling for "protocol-relative url" returns examples like //some-resource, also warnings that nowadays its an "anti-pattern". So, why/when would I use a protocol-relative url vs root-relative? Seems as if root-relative works fine?

Comment: “//resources.mysite.bar/foo.gif” would be “correct” from both HTTP and HTTPS pages hosted on “www.mysite.bar”. Under an HTTPS page there would not be security warning for mixed-HTTP/HTTPS content. Root-relative would restrict to “www.mysite.bar” content alone.

Comment: tldr; root-relative works the same as protocol-relative if and only if the domain is the same.

Comment: Ah. So the most valuable security-wise when loading resources from a different domain, like saying "if this page is https, these resources also need to be https". Thanks 2864740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2864740

> //resources.mysite.bar/foo.gif” would be “correct” from both HTTP and
>   HTTPS pages hosted on “www.mysite.bar”. Under an HTTPS page there
>   would not be security warning for mixed-HTTP/HTTPS content.
>   Root-relative would restrict to “www.mysite.bar” content alone.

Thanks @user2864740